# validity of "+" operator while using "<<"

Tags: c++, cout

I have question for printing text on the screen. I though that there is no valid "+" operator for out streaming text. why is this one valid:

```
std::cout <<  ("print this number " + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(5) + ". " ) << std::endl;
```

although there is complie error for this:

```
std::cout <<  ("print this number " + "5" + ". " ) << std::endl;
```

error: invalid operands of types ‘const char [19]’ and ‘const char [2]’ to binary ‘operator+’

I use **gcc 4.7.3** and C++03.

Comment: you use the `+` operator if a string object. Note the parenthesis

Comment: `operator +` for `std::string:` is used here. What is wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`boost::lexical_cast` returns an `std::string` which has `operator +(const char *, const std::string&)` and `operator +(const std::string&, const char *)` defined for it. So your code gets equivalent to:

```
std::cout << std::string("print this number 5. ") << std::endl;
```

There is no invocation of `operator +` with `std::ostream` arguments.

In your second line you try to add arrays of chars (`const char [19]` and `const char [2]` for example), which is an error by the language rules.

Answer (score 3):

It's because the expression within the parentheses is evaluated first.

The *type* of `boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(5)` is `std::string`. That has overloaded `+` operators for `const char*` (on both sides), which return a `std::string`.

So the *type* of the expression in the parentheses is a `std::string`, and the stream has an overloaded `<<` for it.

Finally `"print this number " + "5" + ". "` will not compile since `+` has no meaning for `const char[]` arguments, even if they *decay* to pointer types.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the `+` is executed before the `<<` - alone by enforcement of the parenthesis. The `+` operator applies to the strings around it, so why would it not work?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing at all to do with streaming. It's simply about the validity of `"print this number " + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(5) + ". "` vs `"print this number " + "5" + ". "`.

The reason the first works is that the second part is a `std::string`, not a string literal. Operator + works for concatenating `std::string`s together or for a mixture of string objects and string literals (C-style strings), but not for pure C-style strings like in the second expression.